# A space which is 0-dimensional but not totally disconnected

Tags: general-topology

Notation: *A space is zero-dimensional if it is $T_1$ and has a basis consisting of clopen sets*.

Is there any topological space which is zero-dimensional but it is not totally disconnected?

Comment: What definition of dimension are you using

Comment: A topological space (X,T) is said to be 0-dimensional if there exists a basis of the topology T consisting of clopen subsets of X

Comment: Doesn't that make the trivial topology on any set into a 0-dimensional space?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. What dimension would you expect the trivial topology to have?

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I see. Your point is that the trivial topology on a set with more than one element is not totally disconnected. Indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Just to be rigorous on the definition we use for dimensionality. Here I use the following definition:

*A space is zero-dimensional if it is $T_1$ and has a basis consisting of clopen sets*.

Every zero-dimensional space is totally disconnected, just by inspection of the relative definitions. In fact, we can say even more: every space $X$ that admits a one-to-one continuous function into a zero-dimensional space is totally disconnected.

The converse is, however, not true. There is indeed a space that is totally disconnected but not-zero dimensional: $E:=\{x \in \ell^{2} : x_i \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ for every } i \}$. It is known in the literature as the [Erdős' space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_space).

Comment: Which means that we don't need the condition that the space should be Hausdorff?

Comment: Correction: every $T_0$ zero-dimensional space is totally disconnected.

Comment: Thanks Alex for pointing me out the separability axioms we assumed in the definition was not clear. Abdellatif, note that zero-dimensionality (the definition I used) implies Hausdorffness. Zero-dimensional implies totally disconnected since every point can be separated from every other point by a clopen set.